# Appending to a vector inside a buffered future - Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

The following code fails with

```
cannot move out of `my_number_vector`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
move out of `my_number_vector`
```

```ini
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3.21"
tokio = "1.19.2"
```

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

let mut my_number_vector = Vec::new();

let the_stream = stream::iter(0..=10);


let response_of_stream = stream_of_urls
            .map(|number| async move {
              number
            })
            .buffer_unordered(2);

 response_of_stream
            .for_each(|number| async move {
               my_number_vector.push(number);
            })
            .await;


}
```

How is it possible to append to a vector in this scenario? I tried using RC and RefCells but it seems I cannot understand the error accurately in order to solve the compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of `Rc/RefCell` was good but, since the async executor may rely on multiple threads, you need the multithreaded equivalent: `Arc/Mutex`.

On top of that, there is a tricky part.
The closure needs access to the vector inside the `Arc/Mutex`, then this closure has to be marked with `move` and the `Arc` has to be cloned.
But, this closure involves an `async` block which also needs access to the vector inside the `Arc/Mutex`, then this block also has to be marked with `move` and the `Arc` has to be cloned again!

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let my_number_vector = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<i32>::new()));

    let the_stream = stream::iter(0..=10);

    let response_of_stream = the_stream // stream_of_urls ???
        .map(|number| async move { number })
        .buffer_unordered(2);

    // clone the Arc to be moved into the closure
    let my_vec_arc = Arc::clone(&my_number_vector);

    response_of_stream
        .for_each(move |number| {
            // clone again the Arc to be moved into the async block
            let my_vec_arc_2 = Arc::clone(&my_vec_arc);

            async move {
                my_vec_arc_2.lock().unwrap().push(number);
            }
        })
        .await;
    println!("{:?}", my_number_vector.lock().unwrap());
    // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
```